# In Swift, how is it possible to put a string as the name of a property of a class in a parametre of a function?

Tags: swift, function, settings

i need to factorise somme calculations, by putting in a parameter of function the name of a propertie, like this `func TotalCalorie(Liste list: [[Movie]], Macro: Int) -> Int` which is, for example `year`, in this case  :

```
struct Movie {
    var title = ""
    var year = 0
    var boxOffice = 0
    var isImportant: Bool
    var isFinished: Bool
    
    init(title: String, year: Int, boxOffice: Int, isImportant: Bool, isFinished: Bool) {
        self.title = title
        self.year = year
        self.boxOffice = boxOffice
        self.isImportant = isImportant
        self.isFinished = isFinished
    }

    static let list1 = [
        Movie(title: "The Shawshank Redemption", year: 1, boxOffice: 2, isImportant: false, isFinished: false),
        Movie(title: "The Godfather", year: 1, boxOffice: 4, isImportant: false, isFinished: false),
        Movie(title: "The Dark Knight", year: 1, boxOffice: 1, isImportant: false, isFinished: false)

        ]
    
    static let list2 = [
        Movie(title: "The Lord of the Rings: The Fellowship of the Ring", year: 2, boxOffice: 3, isImportant: false, isFinished: false),
        Movie(title: "Inception", year: 2, boxOffice: 1, isImportant: false, isFinished: false)
        ]
    
    static let list2Bis = [
        Movie(title: "The Lord of the Rings: The Fellowship of the Ring", year: 2, boxOffice: 4, isImportant: false, isFinished: false),
        Movie(title: "Inception", year: 2, boxOffice: 6, isImportant: false, isFinished: false)
        ]
    
    static let list3 = [list1, list2, list2Bis]
    
    static let nomsDesRepas: [String] = ["Petit Déjeuner", "Collation 11h"]
}



func TotalCalorie(Liste list: [[Movie]], Macro: Int) -> Int { // It's here
var totalsection = 0
var totalcalorie = 0
    
    for xxx in 0..<list.count {
        totalsection = 0
        
        for yyy in 0..<list[xxx].count {
            
        totalsection += list[xxx][yyy].year
}
    totalcalorie += totalsection
}
    return totalcalorie
}

let calories = TotalCalorie(Liste: Movie.list3, Macro: .year)
print(calories)
```

I have to put year or boxOffice in the parametres of my function.
how could i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using **`Mirror`** here.

Use a `String` type parameter in the method and use it to get the property's `value` using `Mirror`.

```
func totalCalorie(liste list: [[Movie]], macro: String) -> Int {
    var totalsection = 0
    var totalcalorie = 0
    
    list.forEach {
        totalsection = 0
        $0.forEach({ (movie) in
            if let value = Mirror(reflecting: movie).children.first(where: { $0.label == macro })?.value as? Int {
                totalsection += value
            }
        })
        totalcalorie += totalsection
    }
    return totalcalorie
}
```

Comment: @Wahib Sure. I’ll try to help.